# No audio in SonicPi using Raspi 2B

Tags: raspberry-pi2, sonic-pi

Just starting with SonicPi but getting no audio from analogue out (headphone socket).
.WAV's placed on Pi play fine using both 'phones and powered speakers but when I launch Sonic Pi and run the very basic program in SonicPi - Nothing.
I expect its blindingly obvious...

Comment: I think this is the wrong place to ask your question

Comment: I thought that after I posted but then again... 
Can you suggest a better place?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I discovered with time practising Sonic pi and there is for sure a better answer :

- everytime you want to use an audio output that were not connected before you  launched the software, it will not work properly (no audio out).
- If you want to switch from headphones to a powered speakers, you have to relaunch the software and it is working.